# How to parse JSON object with array retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

how to fetch JSON object with array using android retrofit. I am using retrofit as web API.

My JSON Response is as follows:-

```
{
    "PnrNumber": "12345665",
    "Status": "SUCCESS",
    "ResponseCode": "200",
    "TrainNumber": "1111",
    "TrainName": "ABC",
    "JourneyClass": "SL",
    "ChatPrepared": "NO",
    "From": "TEST1",
    "To": "TEST2",
    "JourneyDate": "2019-10-01",
    "Passangers": [
        {
            "Passenger": "Passenger 1",
            "BookingStatus": "CNF/S4/18",
            "CurrentStatus": "CNF/S4/18"
        },
        {
            "Passenger": "Passenger 2",
            "BookingStatus": "CNF/S4/19",
            "CurrentStatus": "CNF/S4/19"
        },
        {
            "Passenger": "Passenger 3",
            "BookingStatus": "CNF/S4/24",
            "CurrentStatus": "CNF/S4/24"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can use the gson to serialize and deserialize the JSON using POJO.

Answer (score 7):

Create your [POJO](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org) Model class from the json response

**Passanger.java**

```
public class Passanger {

@SerializedName("Passenger")
@Expose
private String passenger;
@SerializedName("BookingStatus")
@Expose
private String bookingStatus;
@SerializedName("CurrentStatus")
@Expose
private String currentStatus;

//implement getter,setter

}
```

**TrainData.java**

```
public class TrainData {

@SerializedName("PnrNumber")
@Expose
private String pnrNumber;
@SerializedName("Status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("ResponseCode")
@Expose
private String responseCode;
@SerializedName("TrainNumber")
@Expose
private String trainNumber;
@SerializedName("TrainName")
@Expose
private String trainName;
@SerializedName("JourneyClass")
@Expose
private String journeyClass;
@SerializedName("ChatPrepared")
@Expose
private String chatPrepared;
@SerializedName("From")
@Expose
private String from;
@SerializedName("To")
@Expose
private String to;
@SerializedName("JourneyDate")
@Expose
private String journeyDate;
@SerializedName("Passangers")
@Expose
private List<Passanger> passangers = null;

//implement getter, setter

}
```

Retrofit api interface

```
public interface Api {

    @GET("/your_api_endpoint")
    Call<TrainData> retriveTrainData();

}
```

Make a request

```
Call<TrainData> call = getRetrofitInstance().create(Api.class).retriveTrainData();
            call.enqueue(new Callback<TrainData>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<TrainData> call, Response<TrainData> response) {
                    if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                         response.body().getPassangers();
                        //...
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<TrainData> call, Throwable t) {
                   //..
                }
            });
```

There are plenty of resources online, for more details you can read the following articles

[vogella](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html)

[androidhive](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/)

[android.jlelse](https://android.jlelse.eu/consuming-rest-api-using-retrofit-library-in-android-ed47aef01ecb)

Answer (score 1):

Create two classes. One for main json object and other one for passenger. Put a ArrayList of Passengers in first class

Comment: can you please send some sample code for this response

Comment: I prefer @shb's answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example :

**Example.java**

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("PnrNumber")
@Expose
private String pnrNumber;
@SerializedName("Status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("ResponseCode")
@Expose
private String responseCode;
@SerializedName("TrainNumber")
@Expose
private String trainNumber;
@SerializedName("TrainName")
@Expose
private String trainName;
@SerializedName("JourneyClass")
@Expose
private String journeyClass;
@SerializedName("ChatPrepared")
@Expose
private String chatPrepared;
@SerializedName("From")
@Expose
private String from;
@SerializedName("To")
@Expose
private String to;
@SerializedName("JourneyDate")
@Expose
private String journeyDate;
@SerializedName("Passangers")
@Expose
private List<Passanger> passangers = null;

public String getPnrNumber() {
return pnrNumber;
}

public void setPnrNumber(String pnrNumber) {
this.pnrNumber = pnrNumber;
}

public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

public String getResponseCode() {
return responseCode;
}

public void setResponseCode(String responseCode) {
this.responseCode = responseCode;
}

public String getTrainNumber() {
return trainNumber;
}

public void setTrainNumber(String trainNumber) {
this.trainNumber = trainNumber;
}

public String getTrainName() {
return trainName;
}

public void setTrainName(String trainName) {
this.trainName = trainName;
}

public String getJourneyClass() {
return journeyClass;
}

public void setJourneyClass(String journeyClass) {
this.journeyClass = journeyClass;
}

public String getChatPrepared() {
return chatPrepared;
}

public void setChatPrepared(String chatPrepared) {
this.chatPrepared = chatPrepared;
}

public String getFrom() {
return from;
}

public void setFrom(String from) {
this.from = from;
}

public String getTo() {
return to;
}

public void setTo(String to) {
this.to = to;
}

public String getJourneyDate() {
return journeyDate;
}

public void setJourneyDate(String journeyDate) {
this.journeyDate = journeyDate;
}

public List<Passanger> getPassangers() {
return passangers;
}

public void setPassangers(List<Passanger> passangers) {
this.passangers = passangers;
}

}
```

**Passanger.Java**

```
public class Passanger {

@SerializedName("Passenger")
@Expose
private String passenger;
@SerializedName("BookingStatus")
@Expose
private String bookingStatus;
@SerializedName("CurrentStatus")
@Expose
private String currentStatus;

public String getPassenger() {
return passenger;
}

public void setPassenger(String passenger) {
this.passenger = passenger;
}

public String getBookingStatus() {
return bookingStatus;
}

public void setBookingStatus(String bookingStatus) {
this.bookingStatus = bookingStatus;
}

public String getCurrentStatus() {
return currentStatus;
}

public void setCurrentStatus(String currentStatus) {
this.currentStatus = currentStatus;
}

}
```

Here are the classes which are generated from the Response which you have provided in the question.
You can use this link to generate the POJO class for JSON response.
[JSON TO POJO](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

**Add this gradle:**

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

**Init the Gson buildr:**

```
private Gson gson;


GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("M/d/yy hh:mm a");
gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

**Parse the JSON using GSON**

```
gson.fromJson(jsonObject.getJSONObject("data").toString(), Example.class);
```

These are the basic steps to parse the JSON using GSON.

For more information you can refer to the below article:

[Parsing JSON on Android using GSON](https://medium.com/quick-code/parsing-json-on-android-using-gson-and-volley-83d6715776f8)

Or Check the GSON official GitHub Repository

[GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)